# Pass 2D Array Info to a method in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, methods

I have an assesment where we have to implement methods in an app to store employees info in a 2D array and display it onscreen. So far the code works ok like this but I can't figure out a way to pass the 2D array information to the case 2 of the switch. It always results in an IndexOutOfRangeException when I try to return the array info from the UserInput method or when creating a method for case 2 and trying to pass the array. This is the code i have, thanks in advance for the help:

```
using System;

namespace EmployeeFileWithMethods
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int numberEmployees = 0;
      string[,] table = new string[numberEmployees, 4];
      string userInput = "1";
      while ( userInput != "0" )
      {

        userInput = Intro();

        switch ( userInput )
        {
          case "1":
            UserInput();
            break;
          case "2":
            Console.Clear();
            for ( int user = 0; user < table.GetLength(0); user++ )
            {
              Console.WriteLine("     User " + ( user + 1 ));
              for ( int row = 0; row < table.GetLength(1); row++ )
              {
                Console.Write(table[user, row] + "\n");
              }
              Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            break;
          case "0":
            break;
          default:
          {
            DefaultCase();
            break;
          }

        }

      }
      Console.WriteLine("Thanks for using the app!");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static string Intro()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("[-------------------------------------------------------------------------------]");
      Console.WriteLine("                        Welcome to the Edinburgh College App \n                             What would you like to do?\n                                   1:Add User\n                                   2:Show User Info\n                                   0:Exit");
      Console.WriteLine("[-------------------------------------------------------------------------------]");
      string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
      return userInput;
    }
    public static void DefaultCase()
    {
      Console.Clear();
      Console.WriteLine("[-------------------------------------------------------------------------------]");
      Console.WriteLine("              The option that you entered is invalid. Please try again.              ");
      Console.WriteLine("[-------------------------------------------------------------------------------]");
    }
    public static void UserInput()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("How many employees does your company have?");
      int numberEmployees = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      string[,] table = new string[numberEmployees, 4];
      for ( int row = 0; row < numberEmployees; row++ )
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Write the Forename of user " + ( row + 1 ));
        string forename = Console.ReadLine();
        table[row, 0] = forename;
        Console.WriteLine("Write the Surname of user " + ( row + 1 ));
        string surname = Console.ReadLine();
        table[row, 1] = surname;

        while ( true )
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Write the Phone of user " + ( row + 1 ));
          string phone = Console.ReadLine();
          if ( phone.Length == 11 )
          {
            table[row, 2] = phone;
            break;
          }
          else
          {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Phone Number. Please Try Again");
            continue;
          }
        }
        while ( true )
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Write the Email of user " + ( row + 1 ));
          string email = Console.ReadLine();
          int charPos = email.IndexOf('@');
          if ( charPos > 0 )
          {
            table[row, 3] = email;
            break;
          }
          else
          {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Email. Please Try Again");
            continue;
          }
        }

      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the exception, but `UserInput` returns nothing and the table initialized in this method is lost at the return. So the table in `Main` has a size for the first dim of 0. You should pass the table as a parameter by ref and remove the table declaration in the method:

```
UserInput(table);

public static void UserInput(ref string[,] table)
```

But you need to resize this array to add new inputs.

A better and more simple and robust and cleaner way is to use a list of a class entity. Here is the code adapted and improved to use a list of an employee entity. I touched the code a minimum but it can be improved and refactored more, especially the `while` loops, and also you can use `int.TryParse` for the number of employees to add.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

```
public class Employee
{
  public string Forename { get; set; }
  public string Surname { get; set; }
  public string Phone { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

```
static private void Main()
{
  var employees = new List<Employee>();
  string userInput = "1";
  while ( userInput != "0" )
  {
    userInput = Intro();
    switch ( userInput )
    {
      case "1":
        UserInput(employees);
        break;
      case "2":
        Console.Clear();
        for ( int index = 0; index < employees.Count; index++ )
        {
          Console.WriteLine("     User " + ( index + 1 ));
          Console.WriteLine("         Forename: " + employees[index].Forename);
          Console.WriteLine("         Surname: " + employees[index].Surname);
          Console.WriteLine("         Phone: " + employees[index].Phone);
          Console.WriteLine("         eMail: " + employees[index].Email);
          Console.WriteLine("");
        }
        break;
      case "0":
        break;
      default:
      {
        DefaultCase();
        break;
      }

    }

  }
  Console.WriteLine("Thanks for using the app!");
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

```
public static void UserInput(List<Employee> employees)
{
  Console.WriteLine("How many employees does your company have?");
  int countEmployees = employees.Count;
  int countEmployeesNew = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  for ( int indexEmployeeNew = 0; indexEmployeeNew < countEmployeesNew; indexEmployeeNew++ )
  {
    int posEmployeeNew = countEmployees + indexEmployeeNew + 1;
    Console.WriteLine("Write the Forename of user " + posEmployeeNew);
    string forename = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Write the Surname of user " + posEmployeeNew);
    string surname = Console.ReadLine();
    string phone = "";
    while ( true )
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Write the Phone of user " + posEmployeeNew);
      phone = Console.ReadLine();
      if ( phone.Length == 11 ) break;
      Console.WriteLine("Invalid Phone Number. Please Try Again");
    }
    string email = "";
    while ( true )
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Write the Email of user " + posEmployeeNew);
      email = Console.ReadLine();
      int charPos = email.IndexOf('@');
      if ( charPos > 0 ) break;
      Console.WriteLine("Invalid Email. Please Try Again");
    }
    employees.Add(new Employee
    {
      Forename = forename,
      Surname = surname,
      Phone = phone,
      Email = email
    });
  }
}
```